# How to define query parameters in [queryParams] directive in other ways in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm recently working on the issues related to queries. While working on a particular issue - I have need to define some query parameters. Here is the code snippet -

```
<a [routerLink]="resultsearch" [queryParams]="{query: result.label,
                                                       verify: false,
                                                       nav: 'filetype,protocol,hosts,authors,collections,namespace,topics,date',
                                                       start: 0,
                                                       indexof: 'off',
                                                       meanCount: '5',
                                                       resource: 'global',
                                                       prefermaskfilter: '',
                                                       rows: 10,
                                                       timezoneOffset: 0}"
          class="rellink">{{result.label}}</a>
```

The code here seems to be a lot messy in a HTML file. I wanted to know is there any way we can define them in `.ts` file of component and then pass the values in [queryParams] directive ? It would be great if someone can guide me in this. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Define the object in your component class and then [bind](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) to it.

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks for giving time to my question. I'm new in this. It would be great if you can provide me answer. I'll understand from it much better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[...]` syntax on an component property is called [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) - it sets the property to the value of whatever [template expression](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#template-expressions) you pass in.

At the minute, you're just passing a simple object directly as the expression, but that's not all you can do - the 'context' of the expression gives you access to all the member variables of your component class. It looks like you've already made use of this for your `routerLink` property and `result`! So, you can easily move the `queryParams` out into your component class and bind to it like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="resultsearch" [queryParams]="queryParams" class="rellink">
        {{result.label}}
    </a>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  resultsearch = "/whatever/your/path/is";    

  queryParams = {
    query: result.label,
    verify: false,
    nav: 'filetype,protocol,hosts,authors,collections,namespace,topics,date',
    start: 0,
    indexof: 'off',
    meanCount: '5',
    resource: 'global',
    prefermaskfilter: '',
    rows: 10,
    timezoneOffset: 0
  };

  result = {
      label: "hello, world"
  };
}
```